# PDF page overflow

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using WKHTMLTOPDF to pdf SEO reports for customers. However I cannot stop the contents of each page overflowing onto the next. So the half of the word shows on Page 1 and the rest at the top of Page 2.

I have tried using CSS page breaks but it does not seem to have any affect. Any ideas?

Comment: Webkit does support `page-break-...` CSS properties, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Add these rules to your stylesheet:

```
div.alwaysbreak { page-break-before: always; }
div.nobreak:before { clear:both; }
div.nobreak{ page-break-inside: avoid;
  /* http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=9#c21 */
}
```

Then wrap your lines or paragraphs with `<div class="nobreak">`. This even works for table rows.